# How to get a media messages URL using the twilio rest api?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to gather the URL of a media message sent in by a user in a python function. In theory (and according to this https://www.twilio.com/blog/retrieving-twilio-mms-image-urls-in-python tutorial) my python code below should work for this:

```
last_message = client.messages.list(limit = 1)
last_message_instance = last_message[0]
media = last_message_instance
media_url = 'https://api.twilio.com' + media.uri[:-5]
```

However, for some reason the media.uri parameter does not return all three sid (AccountSid, MessageSid, Sid) strings needed for the url. The url should be composed of:

`https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages/{MessageSid}/Media/{Sid}.json`

The .uri returns only my AccountSid and the sent message's MessageSid (interestingly, labelled as Sid in the json message as shown below)

```
"sid": "MMbde22b567bf7e3c77fcd4fe01d286446",
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to find the Media/{Sid} term I need (this typically begins with MEXxXxXxX) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you are only making the request to the API to get a message, which is why you do not have the detail about the media.

You can request the media for the message by calling `last_message_instance.media.list()`. The result of that will be a list of media objects from which you can get the media URL.

```py
last_message = client.messages.list(limit = 1)
last_message_instance = last_message[0]
    for media in last_message_instance.media.list():
        media_url = 'https://api.twilio.com' + media.uri[:-5]
        print(media_url)
```

Comment: ahhhh I see! so the .media call returns all the info media-specific to the message in question where as .messages just gives the overview of that message and not the breakdown of the media etc?

Comment: Yep, the [media resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/media-resource) is a sub resource under the message resource and has all the information you’re looking for.

Comment: Hey @FredS, if this helped would you mind marking it as correct so that other people can see that it helped too? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the documentation for this?  The only `python-twilio` documentation I have found is very basic.

Comment: @jrsupplee The documentation is part of the API documentation. Make sure you have Python chosen and you will see examples of all API methods in Python. Check out the [media resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/media-resource?code-sample=code-fetch-media&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=8.x) for example.